# SQL Server query to get oldest and newest value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with ChangeDate, OldValue, NewValue like shown below:

| changeOrder | oldValue | newValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ID1 | ID2 |
| 1 | ID2 | ID3 |
| 2 | ID6 | ID7 |
| 3 | ID3 | ID4 |
| 4 | ID7 | ID8 |

The ID's in reality are of type STRING, is it possible to get the first and last changes, for example the below result ?

| Oldest | Newest |
| --- | --- |
| ID1 | ID4 |
| ID6 | ID8 |

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What do the values in the "Oldest" and the "Newest" columns represent? The expected results do not make sense to me given the sample data.

Comment: Fixed ! The oldest and newest are the first and last values of the chain. Hope it is clear for you !

Comment: SQL Server or BigQuery?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE chains AS (
  SELECT 1 pos, GENERATE_UUID() AS part, oldValue, newValue
    FROM sample JOIN (
      SELECT v AS oldValue FROM sample, UNNEST([oldValue, newValue]) v
       GROUP BY 1 HAVING COUNT(v) = 1
    ) USING (oldValue)
   UNION ALL
  SELECT pos + 1, part, s.oldValue, s.newValue 
    FROM chains c JOIN sample s ON c.newValue = s.oldValue
)
SELECT DISTINCT
       FIRST_VALUE(oldValue) OVER w AS Oldest,
       LAST_VALUE(newValue) OVER w AS Newest
   FROM chains
 WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY part ORDER BY pos ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider also below approach

```
with recursive iterations as (
  select 1 pos, oldValue, newValue from your_table
  where not oldValue in (select newValue from your_table)
  union all
  select pos + 1, i.oldValue, t.newValue from iterations i
  join your_table t on i.newValue = t.oldValue
) 
select oldValue as Oldest, newValue as Newest 
from iterations
qualify 1 = row_number() over(partition by oldValue order by pos desc)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]